# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kill_cursors' when nltk is imported

Tags: python, nltk, pymongo

If I use a pymongo cursor and have the `nltk` package imported, I get this error.  I'm not sure if this is a bug, or if I can fix this somehow:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Cursor.__del__ of <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x054D0210>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo-3.0.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pymongo\cursor.py", line 211, in __del__
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo-3.0.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pymongo\cursor.py", line 271, in __die
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo-3.0.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 833, in close_cursor
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pymongo-3.0.2-py3.4-win32.egg\pymongo\cursor_manager.py", line 56, in close
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kill_cursors'
```

I'm using `Python 3.4`, `Pymongo 3.0.2`, and `nltk 3.0.2`.

Here is a simple script I can use to reproduce the error:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import nltk

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test
coll = db.restaurants

curs = coll.find()
curs.next()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

**EDIT:** This error occurs **only** when `nltk` is imported. If I comment the `import nltk` line out, the error does not occur.

Comment: Add `assert curs is not None` as the second to the last line. It's possible 'curs' is  `None`, which probably results from an empty `restaurants`

Comment: @PeteCacioppi The error persists using any non-empty collection, that was just an example.